# I have extra gold from the alternate way of getting starting equipment. What should I do with the extra money?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, equipment

I was using the alternate way to get equipment in Chapter 5 of the PHB (D&D 5e)  as a Fighter and rolled 160 GP, which I spent on Studded Leather Armor, a Longsword, the Explorer's Pack, a Crossbow Bolt Case, a Light Crossbow, 20 Crossbow Bolts, and a Dagger, and still have 61 GP to spend on equipment. I have no idea what to do with the extra money as I've bought all the equipment I want. I don't think the PHB addressed this and don't know what the rules say. What do the rules say on what to do with the extra money?

Comment: Do either of the following answer your question: "[If I use the starting wealth rolls of my class, do I keep any remaining money left over?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165335)" or "[If you take starting gold, do you get starting equipment as well?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113006)"? The first establishes that you can keep leftover gp/money/gold from character creation and the latter establishes that if you roll for starting wealth based on your class, you forfeit the starting equipment from both your class *and* your background.

Comment: Medix2's first question does answer my question.